# Invalid identifier when using natural join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting

> ORA-00904: "E"."MANAGER_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error en la línea: 323, columna: 77

With the following code. The position 323 column 77 refers to position 5 column 6 in this piece of code

```
    select concat (concat(concat('Id: ',e.employee_id),
    concat ('',e.first_name)),concat('. ',e.last_name)) as "Employee info", 
    job_title, salary, department_name, 
    (select first_name from employees 
    where e.manager_id=employee_id) as "Manager name"
    from employees e 
    natural join jobs natural join departments;
```

If I do the query "isolated", as:

```
select e.first_name as "Worker name", nvl((select first_name from employees where e.manager_id=employee_id),'Sin manager') as "Manager name"
from employees e
order by e.employee_id;
```

I don't know if it matters, but the database is the built-in hr database from oracle

EDIT: another possibility i reached, apart from the answers, is the following

```
select concat (concat(concat('Id: ',e.employee_id),
concat (' ',e.first_name)),
concat('. ',e.last_name)) as "Employee info", 
job_title, e.salary, department_name, m.first_name, m.employee_id
from employees e join jobs j
on (e.job_id = j.job_id)
join departments d
on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
join employees m
on (e.manager_id=m.employee_id)
order by e.employee_id;
```

the only problem is that is does not show the employees with no manager assigned.

Comment: Forget about that NATURAL JOIN construction. Always specify the JOIN columns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use natural join!  I describe it as an "abomination" because it uses columns that merely have the same *names*, rather than properly declared foreign key relationships.  A relation database should really be doing "natural" joins on the declared relationships, not on string matching.

It also makes queries harder to decipher and maintain, because the join keys are not explicit in the query.  Adding a column can break existing queries, and be quite hard to debug.

You can also simplify the logic for concatenating strings.

I think the query you want looks more like this:

```
select ('Id: ' || e.employee_id  || e.first_name || '.', e.last_name) as Employee_info, 
       j.job_title, e.salary, d.department_name, 
       (select em.
        from employees em
        where e.manager_id = em.employee_id
      ) as Manager_name
from employees e join
     jobs j
     on e.job_id = j.job_id join
     departments d
     on e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

Comment: It works as you said, providing some writing mistakes, but the idea is correct. By the way, I'm going to start replacing concat by ||. Your code is much cleaner